# Main method error in testing Stopwatch Object

Tags: java, stopwatch

I have an exercise that I am working on for programming class. I am getting an odd error that seems very basic, yet I am having trouble debugging it.

The code, when referenced, creates the standard StopWatch object with several instance methods associated with it. I created a main method at the bottom of the code in order to test each method in the StopWatch class to make sure it is working correctly.

Currently, when I run the program I get an error that says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main.
```

I clearly have a main method in this class so I am not sure why I am getting this error.

The main method implements the Gambler's ruin program for testing. I am currently trying to test the stop() and elapsedTime() methods. The full code is enclosed below:

```
/* Notes:
 * Start is the date of birth of the object. Most stopwatch don't keep track of when they were 
 * created.
 */

public class Stopwatch {

    public long startTime; //The creation time of the stopwatch
    public long totalTime; //Total time since watch was zeroed
    boolean running = false;      //This will flag if the watch is started or stopped

    public Stopwatch() //First instance method called Stopwatch. What the client will use to create Stopwatch. This serves as the constructor.
    {
            start();
    }

     public void start()
     {
         startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         running = true;
     }

     public void stop()
     {
         if(running) {
             totalTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
             running = false;
         }

     }

     public double elapsedTime()
     {
         if(running){
             return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
         }
         else{
             return 0; //If the watch isn't currently running, return a 0 value.
         }
     }

     public void zero()
     {
         totalTime = 0;
         start();
     }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Run T experiments that start with $stake and terminate on $0 or $goal.

                Stopwatch program_time = new Stopwatch();
                int stake = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                int goal = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                int T = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
                int bets = 0;
                int wins = 0;
                for (int t = 0; t < T; t++)
                { 
                    // Run one experiment

                    int cash = stake;
                    while (cash > 0 && cash < goal)
                    {
                        // Simulate one bet.

                        bets = bets + 1;
                        if (Math.random() < 0.5)
                        {
                            cash = cash + 1;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            cash = cash - 1;
                        }
                    } // Cash is either going to be at $0 (ruin) or $goal (win)
                if (cash == goal)
                {
                    wins = wins + 1;
                }

            }
                System.out.println(100 * wins / T + "% wins");
                System.out.println("Avg # bets: " + bets/T);
                program_time.stop();
                System.out.println(program_time.elapsedTime());

        }

}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Just copy/paste the exception message.

Comment: The code is fine. How are you starting the program?

Comment: Oh ok. All it says is.....Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

Comment: code is fine. works for me and print > run Stopwatch 1 2 3
66% wins
Avg # bets: 1
0.0

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting. I am trying to run the program in Eclipse currently. I have 100 200 1000 as the three parameters. And then I just click "run" in Eclipse and it immediately returns that error message.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file and class names -- they must match exactly, even with upper and lower case.

Check whether the [Classpath](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/background/13files_and_directories/20classpath.html) is correct or not.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've checked the class name and file name and they do match exactly. I'm using Eclipse and it will usually flag it if they don't match even before you run the program. How would I check the Classpath?

Comment: Look at the link that i have provided in my answer